# Magento2 customer account creation, save boolean value in attribute

Tags: php, magento, magento2

So, as the title says, i've added some new attributes in my customer entity, one of which is a boolean, as you can see from the code in `setup/InstallData.php`

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'azienda', [
        'type' => 'int',
        'label' => 'Azienda',
        'input' => 'boolean',
        'source' => '',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'position' => 333,
        'system' => false,
        'backend' => ''
    ]);
```

and i've also created the frontend layout override for `"customer_account_create"`, everything works fine, other text fields i've added  are saved correctly but i can't get it to save in my database this `"azienda"` attribute which is a boolean. I've tried checkboxes, radiobuttons, textfields with **"yes", "true" and "1",** whatever i put in that field the boolean attribute will be always unchecked (false) after registration.

Tried to add `"default" => 1` in the entity array but it still doesn't save the value as true/checked

Hope i've explained my issue well enough, i feel like it's something small that i'm doing wrong but i can't figure out what it is. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i've managed to fix it, in the end it wasn't something hard or impossibile to find.

I did what i should have done from the beginning, check how the "subscribe to newsletter" was being saved and i've noticed that the `<input type="checkbox">`  had the `value="1"` property, so i've put it in my checkbox and now it works. Leaving here the code if someone has my same problem.

```
    <div class="field choice newsletter">
        <input type="checkbox" name="azienda" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Azienda')) ?>" value="1" id="azienda" class="checkbox">
        <label for="azienda" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Azienda')) ?></span></label>
    </div>
```

From what i understand this works because the checkboxes will be added to the post request ONLY if they are checked with the `on` value but if we add the `value="1"` property that gets sent instead and when Magento2 receives `azienda -> 1` it saves it correctly in my user entity